# 100% Height columns

Tags: jquery, height, css

I have created a responsive layout which you can find here:  http://pixelcakecreative.com/cimlife/responsive/

The left and right columns are simply placeholders for a site skin (left and right full page advertisement). I need both of these columns to extend to the very bottom of the page. Both `html` and `body` have a height of 100%, but for some reason I cannot get these columns to extend to the bottom with `min-height:100%`

Any ideas? I am looking for a pure css solution, but jquery is an option.

Comment: They only show up with browser width 1206 px+, FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery solution would be:

```
// Set Left Column ONLY if Shorter than Document Height //
if ($('#toLeft').height() < $(document).height()){
    $('#toLeft').css('height', $(document).height()+'px');
}

// Set Right Column ONLY if Shorter than Document Height //
if ($('#toRight').height() < $(document).height()){
    $('#toRight').css('height', $(document).height()+'px');
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this is a great solution. Will most likely end up using this unless I can dig up a css solution!

Comment: I tried this (currently live) and it does not seem to be working correctly. It modifies the height, but not to 100%. Take a look, any ideas?

Comment: I see its working on the right column but not the left; give me a sec to take a closer look.

Comment: nevermind above comment. The reason why it wasn't working because the selectors were incorrect. They should be #toLeft and #toRight

Answer (score 1):

ugg.. yes quirk. i usualy use the $(document).height() for that stuf. the body height is usualy only as hi as the content needs it to be so the 100% does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use clearfix: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html It's pure CSS

Comment: there is a clearfix already in my css using a class of .group. I tried adding that to both columns and they disappear

Comment: Then just go with jquery -> @dSquared

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `height: 100%` to all parent divs, not only html or body.

This should fix your website:

```
#toLeft, #colA, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
}
```

And

```
#your-container {
     height: 100%;
}
```

This one work for me.